# NSNetServiceBrowser cannot find services whereas NsdManager discovering it for android

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, bonjour

I have written my bonjour discovery code for service of type `_coap._udp.`.

```
static NSString* kTRServiceType = @"_coap._udp.";
static NSString* kTRDomain      = @"";


-(void) startBrowsing{
[self.serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:kTRServiceType inDomain:kTRDomain];}
```

Its discovering 2 services out of 3 whereas NsdManager discovering all 3.

My NSNetServiceBrowser object is not local as this could be a general mistake.

One service that NSNetServiceBrowser is not discovering is also not visible in Bonjour Browser App. But when i do Reload Services in Bonjour Browser App that service become discoverable .Its like reload services awakes my sleeping published service. Its really strange.